# Plagiarised tag wiki for [gs-vlookup]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki, plagiarism

In the [gs-vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-vlookup) wiki there is a verbatim copy from the google help pages. Which is linked at the bottom with a "Reference" link. Not really the due attribution if you ask me. Could a moderator remove the plagiarised content.

Comment: For future reference, a flag is a more effective way of bringing a problem like this to a moderator's attention. You won't be alone; we have a number of users who regularly raise flags like this, and they are very appreciated.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't sure what to flag, as there isn't a flag on the tag page ;)

Comment: Flag a post. Any post will do. Pick one of your own posts, or better yet, a post by the user who submitted the plagiarized edit. Just be clear in the flag message about what you're actually flagging. A link to the tag wiki revision page is optimal; it gets us exactly where we need to be to see and handle the problem.